# NSMutableString + webService

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm tryng to consume a web service, but when the element name change, change all others ...

```
-(void)callWebService {
    _estacionamentoAdd = [[Estacionamento alloc]init];
    NSString *url = @"http://urlfromws";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

//when get the value of response

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if(!soapResults)
    {
        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"stringFound:%@", string);
    [soapResults setString:string];
}
```

//when receive response

```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
 {
     if(!soapResults)
    {
        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }


if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"id"])
{
 id = [soapResults intValue];
}
else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
{
    name = soapResults;
}
else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"adress"])
{
    adress = soapResults;

 }
[soapResults setString:@""];

    }
```

when element name is "name or adress" the id and the name are equal to adress

When elementName is id...the id = soapResults. Ok, but when the elementName is Adress, adress= soapResults and the id change too. Why?

Comment: there is a question here!? sorry but.. dont see it.. please edit your question

Comment: Yes, there`s a question. Edited

Comment: You don't need to change the title to show that your question has been solved, just accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

well I only see that name and adress will always be @"" AND identical.

e.g.

```
...
name = soapResults; //NOT copied.. name and soapResults are the same object
... 
[soapResults setString:@""]; //affects name too, as they are the same
```

same for address but not for id because that's an Integer, not an Object

- name = address = soapResults...

you may want to copy the value

```
name = [soapResults description];
...
address = [soapResults description];
```

---

other issue:
dont use [soapResults setString:newString] either in the foundCharacters, use appendString (foundCharacters gets called n times)

Comment: soapResults is an NSMutableString that contains the value of field

Comment: yes and it is reused over and over and name / address just POINT to it

Comment: dont use [soapResults setString:newString] either in the foundCharacters, use appendString (foundCharacters gets called n times)

Comment: sorry you didnt get it, append is correct -- anways, glad your code works :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

//always release the NSMutableString

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if(soapResults) {
    [soapResults release];
    soapResults = nil;
}

    soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

NSLog(@"stringFound:%@", string);
[soapResults appendString:string];
```

}